# NineFind - Which 9 Numbers Are Correct?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, calculation-puzzle

[image: NineFind Hard Puzzle]

Text Version:

```
 8    8    8    4    8    9
 8    7    7    3    3    9
(5)   4    9    6   (1)   7
 3    8    9    6    7    4
 2    6    9    8    9    4
 7    7    3    6    3    2
```

From the website [NineFind.com](http://ninefind.com/), instructions are:

"Select the digits from 1 to 9 in the grid once each so that each row and column adds up to 9 or less."

Unlike Sudoku and most number puzzles, this puzzle has all of its squares filled in. Your goal is to find, and circle, the 9 correct numbers, while removing the incorrect numbers along the way. If a number is already circled, that must be the correct one for that particular number, and other boxes with that same number can be removed. Other numbers can be removed using logic, i.e. "*This number can't exist here, otherwise it will force the row or column to add up to more than 9.*"

Remove numbers by crossing them out or placing an X over them. Only nine squares will remain; not every row and column needs to have a number in it, and some rows and columns will add up to less to 9.

You never have to guess. Logic will always be enough to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the easy deductions:

> [image]

Next,

> note that all three 4s are in the same row or column as the top-right 9. So that 9 must be unused (shaded).
>
>  Now the 9s can be used the same way to rule out the 7 in row 2, column 3; the 7s can rule out the 8 in row 4, column 1; the 8s can rule out the 4 in row 1, column 4.
>
>  [image]

And now repeat:

> The 4 now rules out the other 9 in its column; the 9s rule out the other 8 in their column, as well as the 3.
>
>  [image]

A new deduction can be done here:

> Columns 2 and 5 must have an 8 and a 7 used there, in either order. Either way, nothing else can be used in those columns, since the rest of the numbers are too big.
>
>  Similarly, rows 4 and 5 must have the 9 and 4. So neither the 6 or 7 there can be used.
>  [image]

And now the rest falls by process of elimination:

> The only 6 left must be used; then the 7 is chosen, then the 8, then the 3, then the 2, and finally the 9 and 4.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Looks great! There are a few different ways to attack it, and this was nicely worded!

Comment: You skipped eliminating R5C4.

Answer (score 0):

The final grid:

> [image]

---

Step by step solution (I’ll clean up if needed in the morning):

1:

> Get rid of numbers in the 5 and 1 rows and columns that make the sum greater than 9 (the four should also be removed):
>
>  [image]

2:

> The fours eradicate the 9 top right. The remaining nines can remove a 7 and the remaining 7s can remove an 8:
>
>  [image]

3:

> 6s eradicate the 8 in the middle. Remaining 8s eradicate a 4, and remaking fours eradicate the 9:
>
>  [image]

4:

> As the remaking fours and nines are in two rows, one must be in one and the other in the other. All numbers in the 9 column can be removed. All numbers greater than 5 can be removed from the 9 and four rows:
>
>  [image]

5:

> From there there is one 6 left, which gets rid of a 7 which leaves one left. That one seven removes an 8 leaving one 8 left too:
>
>  [image]

6:

> Finally, the 8 eradicating a 3 causes a chain reaction to reach the final grid:
>
>  [image]

Comment: I've downvoted because posting an extremely barebones answer that appears to be solely for "reserving a spot" is... generally considered bad for the health of the site, at the very least.

Comment: @Deusovi ik and I’m sorry, I shouldnt have donethis, I’m  just up late at night and need to crop and edit a load of photos, I’ll try and edit it all in one big go and quickly

Comment: @Deusovi I've upvoted because the answer is correct. Also, the tactic of getting the answer in quickly is used by everyone, isn't illegal and is just the nature of the game.

Comment: @Deusovi and jens I’ve edited so it’s complete, I had a full explanation written out in my edit, I just hadn’t finished processing the pictures which takes ages on mobile. Apologies, won’t do in the future!! And yeah although it’s not illegal, it’s definitely not in the interest of the site, it makes things too competitive and less fun. I don’t feel too bad here because I had a full answer, and editing the pictures here took me an extra 5 or 6 minutes so overall I don’t think it was too bad, but I’ll try and avoid doing so in the future

Comment: @Jens It's not about "tactics" or "the game" -- this is about answer quality. We should not encourage answers that are intentionally subpar in order to be fast; upvotes are not just for answers that are correct but answers that are *high-quality*, and an answer that is only half-finished is decidedly *not* high-quality. [...]

Comment: [...] ([This meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6705/partial-answers-and-list-of-clues-puzzles) is fairly applicable here too: see the last few paragraphs of my answer there, and Rubio's followup comments, for more thoughts on this.)

Comment: @Deusovi If we use your logic, no partial answers should ever be allowed. They are by definition subpar, as they don't even answer the question posed! But we do allow partial answers. A correct answer must have at least as much "quality" as a partial answer, as it actually answers the question posed! So why downvote a correct answer? Your logic doesn't work. BTW, the link you refer to concerns partial answers. This is not a partial answer.

Comment: @Jens This *was* a partial answer at the time of my first comment. See [the first revision, in the edit history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/revisions/96468/1). (The meta post *does* apply to some extent to other, non-partial, answers that initially sacrifice quality for speed-of-answering. But this answer *was* originally very incomplete.)

Comment: The final solution and walkthrough looks great and is very nicely worded!